# How to traverse table elements in jquery under div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jQuery. I have no problem in traversing normal table element but I am stuck here:

```html
<div id="compare-prices" class="" style="display:block;">
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="stock_4 featured">
                <td class="store-logo">
                    <div>
                        <a href="" title="Lenovo K6 Power 32 GB (Grey) 3GB RAM, Dual SIM 4G" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-esnm="Tata Cliq (200)">
                            <img src="img/s/tatacliq.png" alt="Tata Cliq">
                            <div class="variant">
                                <table cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="stock_4">

                                            <td class="name">
                                                <a href="" title="Redmi Note 4 (Dark Grey, 64 GB)" target="_blank">
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="price">Rs. 12,999 </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="price">
                    <div>Rs. 9,085</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="stock_4 featured">
                <td class="store-logo">
                    <div>
                        <a href="" title="Lenovo K6 Power (Grey, 32 GB)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-esnm="Flipkart (9)">
                            <img src="img/s/flipkart.png" alt="Flipkart">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <td class="price">
                        <div>Rs. 9,999</div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then how can I only parse information from main table not from `div > variant` table. Although it has same `tr` class?

I am trying like this:

```
$('.stock_4').closest('#compare-prices').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('.price').text());
});
```

but it give the price of div>variant table also.

Comment: so is it confirmed that the price & href will always come under a tr by class ="stock_4" ?

Comment: Please add JavaScript code, you're using for traversing

Comment: Yes @RohitasBehera

Comment: There are lots of ways to traverse the DOM in jQuery. I'd suggest you read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: you could use the .not() selector to skip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use immediate child selector 
 ***>***

    $('#mainTable > tbody  > tr').each(function(index , item) {
        var itemsrc = $(item).find('img').attr("src")  // will give src
        var price  = $(item).find('.price div').text()  // will give price

        console.log(itemsrc ,price );
    })



Please have a look on the entire solution
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#mainTable > tbody  > tr').each(function(index , item) {
  var itemsrc = $(item).find('img').attr("src")  // will give src
  var price  = $(item).find('.price div').text()  // will give price
  
  console.log(itemsrc ,price );
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="compare-prices" class="" style="display:block;">
    <table id="mainTable" cellspacing="0"  border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="stock_4 featured">
                <td class="store-logo">
                    <div>
                        <a href="" title="Lenovo K6 Power 32 GB (Grey) 3GB RAM, Dual SIM 4G" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-esnm="Tata Cliq (200)">
                            <img src="img/s/tatacliq.png" alt="Tata Cliq">
                            <div class="variant">
                                <table cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="stock_4">

                                            <td class="name">
                                                <a href="" title="Redmi Note 4 (Dark Grey, 64 GB)" target="_blank">
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="price">Rs. 12,999 </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="price">
                    <div>Rs. 9,085</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="stock_4 featured">
                <td class="store-logo">
                    <div>
                        <a href="" title="Lenovo K6 Power (Grey, 32 GB)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-esnm="Flipkart (9)">
                            <img src="img/s/flipkart.png" alt="Flipkart">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <td class="price">
                        <div>Rs. 9,999</div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can u add jsfiddle??

Comment: no need of js fiddle...i have added a working snippet & updated this answer

Comment: my question is not this.Please see question again. if another table is also there  inside table of same name.then how would i get result of main table??

Comment: yeah i got it...so you want to skip the variant table ..am i correct ?

Comment: yeah  when i do variant table result also display

Comment: yeah you gotta use **not(".variant")** to skip the unneeded table

Comment: can you  update the the table html with the variant inside so that i can help out too

Comment: id="compare-prices" is not useful??

Comment: ok...I solved by giving an ID to the main table...I am updating my answer